# multi threading DB access via ADO

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I made a basic class design to work in multi threads with ADO / MSSQL database
The complete class design is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274279/how-to-paint-by-multi-threading-into-a-tbitmap)

the basic thread code goes like this :

```
constructor PaintBitmapThread.Create(bmp_width, bmp_height: Integer;
  server, databasename, tablename, sqlstr: String; ThreadId: Integer);
begin
    FBitmap  :=TBitmap.create;
    FBitmap.Width := bmp_width;
    FBitmap.Height := bmp_height;
    FBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

    FConnection :=TAdoConnection.Create(nil);
    fserver := server;
    fdatabasename := databasename;
    ftablename  := tablename;

    FConnection.LoginPrompt := false;
    ConnecttoDatabase(fserver, fdatabasename, FConnection)

end;

destructor PaintBitmapThread.destroy;
begin
   FBitmap.Free;
   FConnection.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure PaintBitmapThread.Execute;
 var
   ThreadQuery : TADOQuery;
   k : integer;
 begin
   inherited;

   CoInitialize(nil) ; //CoInitialize was not called

   ThreadQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil) ;
   try
// ADO DB THREAD MUST USE OWN CONNECTION
     ThreadQuery.Connection := FConnection;
     ThreadQuery.CursorLocation := clUseServer;
     ThreadQuery.LockType := ltReadOnly;
     ThreadQuery.CursorType := ctOpenForwardOnly;
     ThreadQuery.SQL.Text := FSQLStr;

     ThreadQuery.Open;
     while NOT ThreadQuery.Eof and NOT Terminated do
        begin



       //Canvas Does NOT Allow Drawing if not called through Synchronize
       //Synchronize(RefreshCount) ;

        ThreadQuery.Next;
       end;
   finally
     ThreadQuery.Free;
   end;

   CoUninitialize()
end;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
     fserver := 'localhost\sqlexpress';
     fdatabase := 'test_wbbugfix';
     ftable := 'obj';

     ServerEdit.Text := fserver;
     DatabaseEdit.Text := fdatabase;
     TableEdit.Text := ftable
end;
```

Before leaving the thread.create constructor I get an AV like the screen dump below [image],

what is wrong with my code ???

Comment: As pointed out in your previous question, I fail to see what performance improvements you are trying to achieve here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message states what is the problem here.
You are creating the thread with the `CreateSuspended` parameter set to `False`. 
This means that the thread will start immediately after calling the constructor.
Any call to `Start` will lead to this exception.

**Solution**

Create the thread with the `CreateSuspended` flag set to `True`.
Now you can start the thread calling the `Start` method.

Besides this problem, I would like to point out that your `TADOConnection` and `TADOQuery` do not live on the same thread. This is because the `PaintBitmapThread` constructor is executed in the context of the thread that creates the `PaintBitmapThread` thread object. You can solve this problem by moving the connection construction code inside the `Execute` method.